# Error when Compiling JUnit from Command Line

Tags: java, windows, command-line, junit

I am trying to implement my own junit test runner in windows command line and my installation is all messed up. Here are my environment variables:

- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
- JUNIT_HOME = C:\JUNIT
- CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;.;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.11.jar;%JUNIT_HOME%\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
- Path = other stuff...; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.8.0_05\bin

When I run "javac TestRunner.java" in the proper directory I consistently get the errors " 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command "

So instead I run "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac" TestRunner.java which compiles fine

Then I try to run "java TestRunner.java" and I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class TestRunner.java" but that class runs fine when I run it from within an editor.

Help! What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
java TestRunner
```

not

```
java TestRunner.java
```

The `java` command is for running compiled Java code, but you're giving it a source file which is confusing it. Read this if you're still confused: [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME var has "jdk1.8.0_05"
Your Path var has "jdk**.**1.8.0_05"

Could be just a typo here of course.

I suggest you adjust your Path var to -> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

If your variables are set correct, you should be able to execute 'java -version' in command prompt from within any folder

Your other problem for running your program should be solved by running is as 'java TestRunner', not 'java TestRunner.java'